# R Shiny Server - how to keep variable value in observeEvent function?

Tags: r, shiny

I created the following simplistic function to increase the counter upon user click on a button:

```
observeEvent(input$go, {
  counter = 1
  print(counter)
  counter <- (counter + 1)
  print(counter)
  })
```

I initialised `counter` as follows:

```
counter = 1
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
...
```

If I click the `Go` button multiple times, I expected the counter to increase constantly by one. However, the output is always the following:

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 1
[1] 2
```

Can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 6):

Try to use `observeEvent` with `reactiveValues`. Minimal working example below:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         actionButton("go", "Go")
      ),
      mainPanel(
         verbatimTextOutput("text")
      )
   )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    v <- reactiveValues(counter = 1L)
    observeEvent(input$go, v$counter <- v$counter + 1L)
    output$text <- renderPrint({
       print(v$counter)
   })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**: Each observeEvent function essentially has its own environment. When the observeEvent is queued and then ends, whatever variables were created in the enclosed environment are cleared.

In your case, each time you queue the observeEvent (using the "go" button), the counter variable starts at 1 and is incremented by 1, but when the event ends, the counter variable removed. So, the next time you queue the event, the counter starts over at 1 and repeats the process. All you need is for the value of the variable to persist outside of the observeEvent function.

**Solution**: R Shiny's solution is to save the counter variable as a "reactive" value, which saves the variable's state throughout the life of the application. [@Artem Klevstov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863950/artem-klevtsov) provides a great example of reactive values in this thread.

Comment: Hi it would be more effective if you provided the correspondent code.